# How to use gulp-load-plugins with Browser-Sync?

Tags: npm, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-load-plugins

I'm at a point in my Gulp usage that it's starting to make sense splitting tasks up into separate files.

For this, I was hoping to use `gulp-load-plugins`, but although my task runs, Browser-Sync doesn't appear to fire / do anything.

Here's my stripped back setup. Not sure where I'm going wrong!

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

function getTask(task) {
    return require('./gulp/tasks/' + task)(gulp, plugins);
}

gulp.task('browser-sync', getTask('browser-sync'));
gulp.task('bs-reload', getTask('bs-reload'));
gulp.task('scripts', getTask('scripts'));

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function(){
    gulp.watch('src/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

**scripts.js (Gulp Task)**

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

module.exports = function(gulp, plugins) {

    return function() {

        return gulp.src([
            'src/js/plugins/**', 
            'src/js/app.js', 
            '!src/js/{libraries,libraries/**}'
        ])
        .pipe(plugins.plumber({
            errorHandler: function(error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            this.emit('end');
        }}))
        .pipe(plugins.concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'))
        .pipe(plugins.rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.uglify({
            preserveComments: 'none'
            //preserveComments: 'some'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/')) // Seems okay up until here...
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({   // ...but this never seems to fire!
            stream: true
        }));

    };

};
```

You'll notice I'm requiring Browser-Sync in my `scripts.js` file, but this is because doing plugins.Browser-Sync wasn't working. I read somewhere that this is because Browser-Sync is not actually a Gulp plugin.

So whilst I don't get any errors and Browser-Sync appears to start up...from then on, my scripts task works, but it doesn't fire the BrowserSync part.

Any help greatly appreciated!

**PS**, Incase it helps, here's my `package.json` file (notice that above I'm presenting you a stripped back version of my `gulpfile.js`).

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MichaelPumo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A frontend Gulp project for WordPress by Michael Pumo.",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "MichaelPumo",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "2.6.5",
    "gulp-postcss": "~6.0.0",
    "autoprefixer-core": "~5.2.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.5.2",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "2.0.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "node-neat": "~1.7.2",
    "gulp-svgmin": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-image-optimization": "~0.1.3",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For anyone wondering or in the dark about this, note that by default `gulp-load-plugins` will only work with NPM packages that are prefixed with '`gulp-`'.

Fortunately, you can change this behaviour and pass the search as an option like so:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
        pattern: '*'
    });
```

In your tasks, you can now reference Browser-Sync as `plugins.browserSync` like so:

**browser-sync.js (Gulp Task)**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(gulp, plugins) {

    return function() {

        plugins.browserSync.init({
            port: 8080,
            proxy: {
                target: 'http://localhost:8888/my-website-path/'
            }
        });

    };

};
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: It surely helped me, why doesnt it need the gulp task around it?  Also, note your plugins can be set like this `var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  overridePattern: true,
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*', '@*/gulp{-,.}*', 'browser-*']
});` So that you dont need to pull in all your dependencies.

Comment: You have to be careful setting this pattern because if you have both `eslint` and `gulp-eslint`declared in `package.json`, the plugin will fail.